# Is it possible to create an array of ctypes pointers to Python objects?

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to implement my own array in Python. I have two parts to this question:

1. How can I create an array of pointers?
2. Is it possible to get a pointer to a non ctype?

Comment: ctypes is a foreign function interface. It's not intended to be a means to extend Python from within Python. You'll have to elaborate on what you're doing, but it sounds like you want a C extension module that implements a custom array type. Have you looked into using NumPy?

Comment: I'll briefly answer your questions, anyway. (1) array types are created using the `*` operator, and (2) `py_object` creates a pointer to a Python object, e.g. `pyobj_array = (ctypes.py_object * 5)();` `pyobj_array[:] = 0, 0.0, u'', [], {}`. Notice that a reference to each object is kept in the `pyobj_array._objects` dict. By incrementing the reference count of each object, this ensures that the pointers remain valid for the lifetime of `pyobj_array`.

Comment: @eryksun In response to why one would do this, I was challenged to create my own list in python so I had to figure out how to make a statically allocated array underneath it first.